# How to use auto login in a remastered LiveCD?

Tags: login-screen, live-cd, remastersys

I have been creating a custom live CD of Ubuntu 11.10 using remastersys, everything goes well except that the live session asks for a login. the login is automatically set as "custom" and the password is blank. this is fine, but I would rather it went direct to the desktop in a live session as you would expect from other distro live cds.

I have asked on the remastersys forums, the question has gotten a lot of views, but no answer as of yet, I am wondering has anyone here remastered a distro and come across the login problem, and if so, how did you fix it?

Comment: [Is this helpful?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Removing_the_.28Casper.29_Autologin)

Comment: Im not sure, is this telling how to remove autoligin for a live session, when i want autologin for a live session, so if i do the reverse, the live session will go direct to the desktop? will this adversely affect login once the sysytem is installed? thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring your login manager on the system to be remastered. Enable autologin there and I believe it will be the same in LiveCD. My root account password saves on remastered LiveCD and on installation of this remaster, so login manager's settings mostly save.
This is just a guess, though.

And you could also look at the new version of remastersys [here](http://www.remastersys.com/forums/index.php?topic=1760.0), they added some options for grub customization and plymouth theme, so I believe you can enable autologin with that version aswell.

If anyone posts any good response, please ignore this one, since these are just guesses.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i should have mentioned that i am already using the latest remastersys and also fragadelic, the dev, earlier offered that having autologin would actually cause problems, though in my case i dont have autologin enabled

Answer (score 0):

for solving this problem i was making Live-Cds the last three weeks day n night 
and i tried every tip and configuration-option in remastersys :-p !

But now i think i found the "problem" and my last 2 Live-Cd making with remastersys
has no login-prompt anymore and starts with auto-login!

First let me tell you that you have to use the DISTRO-MODE and NOT the BACKUP-MODE!
In Backup-Mode of Remastersys always your last user and password is saved!

And it really helps if you had a clean system-Install with Auto-login choosen first and NO encryption of your homefolder!

It doesn t matter if you have make password-prompt later on- but if you make your live-cd make Auto-Login ON again!

And now comes the "Trick": In the Gdm-Login-Manager-Preferences you can choose timebased Auto-Login under the normal Auto-Login option! THIS YOU HAVE TO MAKE ALWAYS ON TOO!!!
for example: 10 seconds or something- but it has to be activated!

For me now it works and every Live-Cd i make with Remastersys is coming with auto-login!
I tried this on Linux Mint 13 but this is based on Ubuntu 12.04 and so it has to work on other Ubuntu-Machines that using GDM/MDM-Login too!?!

Don't change anything in Users/groups-GUI!!!

I hope somebody will help this! I was going really mad about not finding out how it works!
And at the end i was thinking: ok, so everybody has to use the login as "custom" without password- but without this prompt it makes more sence!

:-)